# find optional middle of string surrounded by lazy, regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python and regex to try to extract the optional middle of a string.

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*?)(HELLO|BYE)?(.*?END)', r'qweHELLOsdfsEND').groups()
('', None, 'qweHELLOsdfsEND') #what I want is ('qwe', 'HELLO', 'sdfsEND')
>>> re.search(r'(.*?)(HELLO|BYE)?(.*?END)', r'qweBLAHsdfsEND').groups()
('', None, 'qweBLAHsdfsEND') #when the middle doesn't match. this is OK
```

How can I extract the optional middle?

Note: This is my first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex fails because the first part is happy with matching the empty string, the second part fails (which is OK since it's optional), so the third part captures all. Solution: Make the first part match anything up to `HELLO` or `END`:

```
>>> re.search(r'((?:(?!HELLO|BYE).)*)(HELLO|BYE)?(.*?END)', r'qweHELLOsdfsEND').groups()
('qwe', 'HELLO', 'sdfsEND')
>>> re.search(r'((?:(?!HELLO|BYE).)*)(HELLO|BYE)?(.*?END)', r'qweBLAHsdfsEND').groups()
('qweBLAHsdfs', None, 'END')
```

Is that acceptable?

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # Try to match the following:
 (?!        # First assert that it's impossible to match
  HELLO|BYE # HELLO or BYE
 )          # at this point in the string.
 .          # If so, match any character.
)*          # Do this any number of times.
```

Comment: Yes that solves my problem! I hadn't come across (?! ) before.

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Lookaround is a great feature.

Comment: That's and excellent tutorial. Really well written and comprehensive. thx

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
try:
    re.search(r'(.*?)(HELLO|BYE)(.*?END)', r'qweHELLOsdfsEND').groups()
except AttributeError:
    print 'no match'
```

Comment: +1: If you want to extract it when it's there, and do something else when it isn't there, then it *isn't really "optional"*. Regexes can be tricky to work out because you often have to reason at a couple different levels at once.